# Some leaks while switching between two views

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, pushviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I use navigation controller to push and pop addColorView over rootView. According to Leaks instrument some objects are leaking when the view is pushed (three Mutable arrays and two mutable dictionaries) with a responsible frame [UITableView _setupTableViewCommon]
When this view is poped another two objects get leaked (UIGobblerGestureRecognizer object and again a mutable array)

```
- (void) addButtonPressed {

    NSLog(@"addButtonPressed");
    AddColorViewController *addColorViewController = [[[AddColorViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addColorViewController animated:YES]; // <-- The Leaks tool points right here
}
```

The question is where should I look for the actual leaks? What on earth is UIGobblerGestureRecognizer?

EDIT 1:
the viewDidLoad method in AddColorViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.listOfLabels = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name", @"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"New";

    [self.tableView initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action:@selector(homeButtonPressed)];
    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveButtonPressed)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;

    [homeButton release];
    [saveButton release];
}
```

...

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            textField.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 170, 30);
            textField.placeholder = @"color";
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        }
        else {
            textField.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 80, 30);
            textField.placeholder = @"0..255";
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        }

        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.tag = [indexPath row] + 1; 
        textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        [cell addSubview:textField];
        [textField release];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listOfLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I would check what you're allocating in addColorViewController's viewDidLoad. As far as the pop, maybe there's an outlet that you want to set to nil in viewDidUnload?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've added the viewDidLoad method, but I believe everything is ok there. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm are you initializing arrays in your cellForRowAtIndexPath? That would be called three times if listOfLabels.count is your # of rows....

Comment: No, there is no arrays there. Just an autoreleased cell and a released textField. In fact it looks strange for me because I never use either Mutable Dictionaries or GobblerGestures, but they are leaking somehow O.o

Comment: Is addColorViewController a subclass of UIViewController or UITableViewController? At this point I should say that I'm feeling sort of stumped and would really just be taking a shot in the dark with any suggestions